# Issue with HTML form

Tags: html, forms, post

I'm having a slight issue with the following piece of code:

```
<form action="submit.php" action="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Card!">
</form>
```

Basically when I'm hitting submit it's going to the URL:

```
http://localhost/submit.php?name=Mike
```

For example rather than just submit.php, I was under the impression that using POST as the method would pass it along through HTTP rather than the URL,  I was wondering why this was happening.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the silly question, long day, I was using action="post" instead of method="post".

Feel a tad silly now...

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you redirect to `http://localhost/submit.php?name=Mike` after dealing with the post data.